# Getting Actions must be plain object in react native redux

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

Hi i'm getting the error `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`but I'm using redux-thunk and I already have some actions with async calls that I'm using.Does someone knows why i'm getting this error ?

```
export function reportUser(userId, idBlocked, raisons) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios({
      url: url,
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        id: userId,
        membres_id: idBlocked,
        raisons: raisons,
      },
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_REPORT_USER', payload: response.data });
        console.log(response.data);
        setTimeout(() => {
          Alert.alert('Le membre a bien été débloqué.');
        }, 500); // Wait nav complete
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You would not have this error if you [set up](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation) the thunk middleware. You say you are using thunk but I don't see the code how you call crateStore in your question.

Comment: I, first thanks for answering ! I'm using thunk and i have the create store in my files, `const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);`. As i said, i'm using others actions with async calls and these actions are working fine.

Comment: Ok, how are you dispatching `reportUser` if that is the action that is giving you the error?